# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database

Trying to connect to the mysql database and get this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource

My dependency in pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.24</version>
</dependency>
```

My connection to the db:

```
datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    serverName: localhost
    databaseName: test
    username: root
    password: mynewpassword
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I am working with IntelliJ IDEA and for resolving this you need just Reload All Maven Projects.

[image]

Comment: the maven auto-import feature was removed last year from intelliJ for...reasons. you should also see a small badge while editing a java file indicating that a maven reimport needs to be done.